# Middle mouse button paste doesnt work in gvim7.3

Tags: vim, mouse, gvim

I recently upgraded myself to `gvim7.3` (from `gvim7.2`) and I've lost my middle-mouse button paste functionality.

Note: This problem is only in `gvim`, my `vim` works as expected.

What magic stuff should I put in my `vimrc` to get the awesome functionality back?

Comment: does holding down shift help?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with the middle mouse button suddenly not pasting in vi.  Following the advice above, I was able to paste normally when starting vi with the `-N -u` switches, so I edited my `.vimrc` file and commented out

```
set mouse=a
```

Doing so brought back the desired paste functionality for me.

Answer (score 1):

What did you do to upgrade? Did you install your distribution's latest gvim package in place of the same distribution's earlier gvim package? Did you build it yourself? Did you upgrade both gvim and vim?

If the upgrade didn't change your vimrc, then there is no reason to believe that changing your vimrc will fix the problem.

In a terminal, start gvim like this:

```
gvim -N -u NONE
```

That will ignore all of your configuration files. Copy some text from somewhere, move your mouse to the gvim window and click the middle mouse button. It should paste whatever you copied. If it didn't, there is something wrong with your build of gvim. Clues may be found in the output of

```
:version
```

If the paste did work, then the problem is in your configuration. Make sure when you run gvim normally that

```
:verbose set mouse?
```

prints "mouse=a". If it doesn't, it will tell you where the value of the 'mouse' option is being changed.

To verify that gvim is seeing your middle mouse click, you can put gvim into insert mode (e.g., type `o`) then type Ctrl-V and click the middle mouse button. Gvim should insert the text "<MiddleMouse>".

If that doesn't reveal the problem, let me know the results and we'll go from there.

Comment: `:verbose set mouse?` says mouse=a and `Ctrl-V Middle Mouse` says <MiddleMouse>

Comment: oh, I should clarify that "Ctrl-C" copy and "middle mouse" works. Its the "select to copy", "middle mouse" that stopped working all of a sudden.

Comment: Do you mean that dragging the mouse over some text in gvim to select it, then middle-clicking the mouse somewhere else in gvim no longer pastes it? Could you give me some sequence of steps that no longer work as you expect, starting from `gvim -N -u NONE` so that I can understand the problem better and can try to reproduce it myself?

Comment: I just fired up gvim 7.2.148 and gvim 7.3.189 on Fedora 11 with `-N -u NONE` and successfully used the left mouse button to select text and the middle mouse button to paste it, both within each gvim instance and between them. So with no configuration files, selecting and pasting seems to work fine on both 7.2 and 7.3.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I added to `~/.vimrc`:

```
set mouse=
```

After that, middle mouse button paste will work again.